# Finding specific compositions of an Integer

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find all compositions of an integer L wherein all parts do not exсeed l and parts less then l cound not be neighbor. Here is my code

```
test[arr0_, ll0_] :=
  Module[{arr = arr0, ll = ll0},
   result = True;
   For[i = 1, i < Length[arr], i++, 
    If[arr[[i]] < ll && arr[[i + 1]] < ll, result = False]];
   result
   ];
frag[L0_, l0_] :=
  Module[{L = L0, l = l0},
   part = IntegerPartitions[L, 2*Ceiling[L/l] + 1, Range[l]];
   part = Flatten[Map[Permutations[#] &, part], 1];
   Select[part, test[#, l] &]
   ];
frag[9, 3]

Output: {{3, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 1}}
```

I guess Mathematica allows to solve this problem much more easier

Comment: aren't there some lists missing in your output, such as e.g. `{1,2,1,2,1,2}`?

Comment: "parts less then l cound not be neighbor" in my case l=3, so 1 and 2 cannot be neighbor

Comment: ah, ok, I understood 1 and 1 (and also 2 and 2) cannot be neighbor. Got it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of solutions posted so far (including yours) is that they could not take into account the limitation on the size and placement of parts of the partitions, and therefore had to consider a much larger search space, unnecessarily.

Here is a recursive solution based on linked lists and not using any built-in functions:

```
ClearAll[parts];
parts[accum_,0,_]:= parts[Flatten[accum]];
parts[_,_?Negative,_]:={};
parts[accum:{_,last_},num_,lim_]/;last<lim:=
    parts[{accum,lim},num-lim,lim];
parts[accum_,num_,lim_]:=
    (parts[{accum,#1},num-#1,lim]&)/@Range[lim];
parts[num_,lim_]:=
    Cases[parts[{},num,lim],parts[x_List]:>x,\[Infinity]];
```

What it does is to build a tree and then pick the valid combinations from it, using `Cases` (bad combinations result in `{}`, while valid ones have the form `parts[combination]`). Since here I have the access to the fine-grained details of the algorithm, I can ensure that a number of bad combinations will be filtered out right when we are building the tree, which reduces the search space significantly.

For example:

```
parts[9, 3]

(* 
   {{1, 3, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 3}, 
   {2, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 3}}
*)
```

This one is also quite reasonable in terms of run-time and memory efficiency:

```
parts[40,5]//Short//AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.163907,{{1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,4},<<6825>>,{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5}}} *)
```

Comment: This is wonderful

Comment: ... it took me longer to understand how you exactly do it than to write my answer. Big +1.

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thanks, but this means that I didn't explain it well. I thought the code is more or less self-explanatory. Perhaps I should have added links to similar solutions I posted before.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: don't base it on my opinion alone, your explanation is great as it is - it just took a bit till I got my head around the `accum` (I just had to work an example, further expl. wouldn't change that, I guess)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks. I find linked lists useful in such cases as this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. Thank you! You are really strong! Maybe you could help me with another problem described here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531330/random-filling-of-l-length-line-with-l-length-segments-discrete-case

Comment: Sorry, but to stay sane, I restricted my helping activities to Mathematica programming only :). Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I post the problem with Mathematica code here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34514/random-filling-of-l-length-line-with-l-length-segments

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood it right, how about this:

```
doIt[int_Integer, l_Integer] := 
   DeleteCases[
     Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[int, int, Range[l]], 1], 
     {___, Alternatives @@ Range[l - 1], Alternatives @@ Range[l - 1], ___}];

doIt[9, 3]
```

> `{{3, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 
>     3}, {1, 3, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 1}}`

are you going to use this on large numbers? That'll be slow... (using `IntegerPartitions` and `Permutation`)

Comment: Yes, I would like to use it for Large numbers

Comment: ok, well, you will definitely like @LeonidShifrin's answer then!

Answer (score 1):

Not neat but another approach...agree scaling issues

```
f[p_, n_] := 
  Select[Select[IntegerPartitions[p], And @@ (# <= n & /@ #) &], 
   Count[#, n] >= Floor[Length[#]/2] &];
test[x_, n_] := 
  Length[Cases[Partition[x, 2, 1], {_?(# < n &), _?(# < n &)}]] == 0;
frag[x_, n_] := 
 Join @@ Map[Select[Permutations[#], test[#, n] &] &, f[x, n]]
```

`frag[9,3]` yields:

```
    {{3, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 
  3}, {1, 3, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 1}}
```

`frag[10,3]`:

```
{{3, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 
  2}, {2, 3, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 3, 
  1}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 2}}
```