# Random filling of L-length line with l-length segments

Tags: random, combinatorics

I have discrete L-length line filled randomly with 2-length segments so its cover line with gaps 0 or 1. So we can describe cover configuration as sequence of gaps such as {0,0,1,0,1}. How I can calculate the probability of any cover? I tried to do it using weighted graphs but it works only for small values of L < 30. Increase the line length on 1 leads to 10-times increase in calculation time. Here is my slow code:

```
l = 2;
detach = Function[{cov, l}, s = Last[cov]; 
Table[Append[cov, Delete[ReplacePart[s, i -> l + Total[s[[i ;; i + 1]]]], i + 1]], {i, 1, Length[s] - 1}]];
getProbability = Function[{cov, l},
   cc = NestWhile[Flatten[(detach[#, l] &) /@ #, 1] &, {cov}, Length@Last@Last@# != 1 &];
   Total[Map[(Apply[Times, #]) &, MapThread[(p = Total[Select[#1, # >= l &] - l + 1]; 
   If[ p === 0, 1, 1/p]) &, {cc,ConstantArray[ConstantArray[l, Length[First[First[cc]]]], Length[cc]]}, 2]]]
 ];
Table[getProbability[{ConstantArray[0, i]}, l] // AbsoluteTiming, {i, l, 10}]

Output: {{0.031540, 1}, {0.000216, 2/3}, {0.000547, 7/15}, {0.002399, 34/105}, {0.013129, 638/2835}, {0.089803, 4876/31185}, {0.694457, 220217/2027025}, {6.223379, 6885458/91216125}, {63.263433, 569311642/10854718875}}
```

Here is example graph:

[image]

Maybe it is possible to solve this problem using recurrence sequence or generating functions?

Comment: Related: [Simulating Theatre puzzle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16458/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an elegant resursive formula which can be efficiently implemented with memoization

```
ClearAll[f];

f[gaps_List, l_: 2] := f[gaps, l] = Sum[f[gaps[[;; n]], l] f[gaps[[n + 1 ;;]], l], 
    {n, Length[gaps] - 1}]/(Total[l + gaps] - 2 l + 1);
f[{_}] = f[{_}, _] = 1;
```

Here `Total[l + gaps] - 2 l + 1` is `L - l + 1` (the number of avaliable positions on the empty line)

```
l = 2;
f[ConstantArray[0, #], l] & /@ Range[l, 10] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000684, {1, 2/3, 7/15, 34/105, 638/2835, 4876/31185, 220217/2027025, 
>    6885458/91216125, 569311642/10854718875}}
> ```

```
f[RandomInteger[l - 1, 30], l] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.062516, 1031/2604060900000}
> ```

It is really fast!

**Proof**

Let us consider final filling. For example ($L=7,\ l=2$)

[image]

One of these segments was chosen first. For example, we choose the segment, which is marked by gray.

[image]

Probability of these choice is $1/(L-l+1)=1/6$ (it doesn't depend on the position). Then we need to fill the empty space to obtain the final filling

[image]

It splits to two independent problems

[image]

In the gap notation this step can be written as

$$
(0,1,0,0) \to (0,1), (0,0)
$$

However, there are another possibilities:

$$
(0,1,0,0) \to (0), (1,0,0)\\
(0,1,0,0) \to (0,1), (0,0)\\
(0,1,0,0) \to (0,1,0), (0)
$$

As a result

$$
p(0,1,0,0) = \frac{1}{6}\bigl(p(0)p(1,0,0)+p(0,1)p(0,0)+p(0,0,1)p(0)\bigr)
$$

In general:

$$
p(g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n) = \frac{1}{L-l+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p(g_1,\ldots,g_i)p(g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n)
$$

Here length $L$ depends on gaps as
$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(l+g_i)-l
$$

Comment: For the simpletons (me) would you please tell how this works?

Comment: Could you give me the reference on this elegant recursive formula in the book or journal publecation?

Comment: @ybeltukov It is really cool! Is it works correctly for any distributions of the gaps?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Surely! I added the proof to my post.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков I don't know any references, I have derived this formula by myself for half an hour. I checked it with your function and results always was the same.

Comment: I am wondering if I don't understand the question.  As I read it this is like the "Theatre puzzle" I linked to (below the question), but looking for a specific filling rather than a proportion.  By my method the specific filling you show (http://i.stack.imgur.com/8XuIC.png) should happen with a probability of ~0.187 yet I do not get a value similar to this from your function (though I may be misapplying it).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get `f[{0, 1, 0, 0}] = 3/16 = 0.1875`. May be you use wrong gaps?

Comment: You're right, I failed to understand the gap notation.

Comment: Now that I can see that it is working: this is really nice. +1  By the way, if you have spare time you should try ProjectEuler.net if you have not done so already; you'd do very well at it!

Comment: @ybeltukov It is really easy! Shame on me. I should think better before asking.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I alredy know about ProjectEuler.net (from your profile!). I used to think that I need to write programs in ordinary languages (I find it boring). Thanks for pointing me to understand it better! Spare time is a problem for be, but there are integersting problems.