# Generate lists with a constraint

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming

I have just started using Mathematica, therefore please excuse possibly stupid questions.

I need to generate a list of specific distributions of $k$ ordered objects into $n>=2k$ cells, such that the order of the objects is preserved and every pair of them is separated by at least one 0-element. The last and the first element also have to be separated by 0, as if the sequence were cyclic.

For example given the set `{1,2,3}` the result should be:

for n<=5:

```
{}
```

for n=6

```
{{1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}}
```

for n=7:

```
{{1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3},
 {0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}}
```

and so on.

I am looking for an efficient solution, which can be applied for large $k$ and $n$.

ps. I know the solution involving generation of all permutations of `{0,0,0,0,1,2,3}` with subsequent rejection of the false sequences but it is certainly very inefficient one.

Comment: You could try to combine `Permutations` with `Riffle` and add enough zeros to the list for larger values of `n`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It can be really useful, if it is possible to split $n-k$ zeros into $k$ non-empty groups. But I hope for a solution similar to that one posted for a similar problem by @Leonid Shifrin: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34468/finding-specific-compositions-of-an-integer. To my sorry I understand almost nothing from this code, but it does work.

Comment: Perhaps you could convert `Table[{i,j,k}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, i+2, 5}, {k, j+2, 7}]` into a recursive function? The Table call produces a list of triplets for where the nonzero entries are positioned.

Answer (score 6):

For performance I shall use `shuffleW` from my answer to [Shuffle product of two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41614/121).
`shuffleW` was coauthored with [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao).

*Note:* my attempt to eliminate `Union` was a failure, producing invalid output.  I am restoring a version with `Union` to correct this.

```
shuffleW[s1_, s2_] := 
  Module[{p, tp, ord},
    p = Permutations @ Join[1 & /@ s1, 0 & /@ s2]\[Transpose];
    tp = BitXor[p, 1];
    ord = Accumulate[p] p + (Accumulate[tp] + Length[s1]) tp;
    Outer[Part, {Join[s1, s2]}, ord, 1][[1]]\[Transpose]
  ]

solution[in_List, n_] /; n < 2 Length[in] := {}  

solution[in_List, n_] := 
  # ⋃ RotateRight[#, {0, 1}] &[
    Flatten /@ shuffleW[ {#, 0} & /@ in, Table[0, {n - 2 Length[in]}] ] ]
```

Test:

```
solution[{1, 2, 3}, 5]

solution[{1, 2, 3}, 6]

solution[{1, 2, 3}, 7]

solution[{}, 7]
```

> ```
> {}
>
> {{0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}}
>
> {{0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3},
>  {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0},
>  {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0}}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

---

#### Carl Woll's comment

[Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) [commented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138472/generate-lists-with-a-constraint/138485#comment373796_138472) on a relation to `Table`.  Here is an implementation of that.

```
solCW[in_, n_] := 
  With[{m = Length@in}, 
    With[{syms = Unique[Table["x", {m}], Temporary]}, 
      Array[{syms[[#]], syms[[# - 1]] + 2 /. List -> -1, n - 2 (m - #)} &, m]
       // MapAt[n - 1 + Sign[syms[[1]] - 1] &, #, {-1, -1}] &
       // Apply[Table[syms, ##] ~Flatten~ (m - 1) &]
       // Map[SparseArray[# -> in, n] &]
       // Normal
    ]
  ]

solCW[{a, b, c}, 7]
```

> ```
> {{a, 0, b, 0, c, 0, 0}, {a, 0, b, 0, 0, c, 0}, {a, 0, 0, b, 0, c, 0},
>  {0, a, 0, b, 0, c, 0}, {0, a, 0, b, 0, 0, c}, {0, a, 0, 0, b, 0, c},
>  {0, 0, a, 0, b, 0, c}}
> ```

Comment: That Shuffle Product question was a fun problem, good to see it put to use...

Comment: Seems to be missing results: `{0,0,1,0,2,0,3}` ?

Comment: And the result `{0,1,0,2,0,3,0}` appears twice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much for your answer and especially for the reference to the Shuffle topic. I wonder however if it is possible still optimize the `shufflew` code in applying to this particular problem, as the latter is much simpler (the elements of one set are all identical). What concerns your answer, is it not faster first to riffle the initial set with $k$ zeros, declare it as a set of pairs `{0,in[[i]]}`, then shuffle it with $n-2k+1$ zeros, and in the end remove the first 0?

Comment: @ciao Oops, didn't check my result well enough.

Comment: @drer Sorry, I should have been more careful; I reasoned that the result should be correct without actually checking it, then went to bed.  I'll give this another go later, and I'll try to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: @drer I fully reviewed my `shuffleW` code and I was not able to find a specific optimization for your particular case.  However I *was* able to make the function significantly faster over-all.  Please make sure you are using the new version in any tests henceforth.

Comment: @ciao While revising this I was able to improve `shuffleW` considerably; I updated the original post and the timings therein (now in 10.1 rather than 7.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Nice, and clean. Would +1 again if I could. Looks like performance/efficiency was not of import despite OP question, based on their rather inefficient self answer.

Comment: @ciao Thank you.  By the way if you feel like working on it I am not happy with `toGaps` from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138146/121 -- can you see a better way to build those "distance tables" I illustrate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'll take a look when time permits: if it's interesting to you, it will surely be to me. I'm working right now on a package to donate to the community with a set of high-performance probability functions that duplicate MMA functionality but are *much* faster (e.g., don't know if you saw my recent [multinomial CDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137883/faster-method-for-cdf-of-multinomial-distribution) ) which is keeping me busy, so it may be a while.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Could you comment on the solution presented in the yesterdays edit of my answer? Is it what you meant with an adaptation of `shuffleW` code?

Comment: @drer Let me take a look.

Comment: @drer I had not considered doing that.  I think it is an adaptation in the way I meant, but at present it is not fast, consistently being more than an order of magnitude slower than `solution` using `shuffleW`.  Possibly compiling the `For` loops would make it competitive.

Comment: I am sure my `For` construction is not optimal for Mathematica, and certainly needs to be optimized. From the other hand it is hard to imagine how to optimize it for the most of "normal" languages. To my sorry I do not understand what do you mean by "solution using shuffleW". Do you mean a solution of my problem?

Comment: @drer By "`solution` using `shuffleW`" I mean my `solution` code at the top of this answer with `f` replaced by `shuffleW`, of course loading that definition from the linked answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is the point I did not understand before.

Comment: @drer If that wasn't clear to you it probably isn't clear to other readers too.  I am going to edit this answer to use the fastest code I have available.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)'s naming [convention](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138485/29734), we have

```
solution[in_List, n_] := With[{l = Length@in},
  Flatten@Riffle[in, #] & /@ Map[ConstantArray[0, #] &, Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n - l, {l}], {2}]
 ]
```

The core of the idea is to use `IntegerPartitions` on the difference between the `n` and `k` to get the different numbers of 0's that go between the numbers. This generates all the lists with zeros at the *end*. To extend it to all of the lists, `Map` the following function over the result:

```
extend = Sequence @@ Table[RotateRight[#, n], {n, 0, FirstPosition[Reverse@#, _?Positive][[1]] - 1}]) &;
```

Usage:

```
extend /@ solution[Range[3], 7]
(* {{1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}} *)
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yes thanks! I figured I'd use your same terminology and obviously forgot to change it between the two. Fixed.

Comment: I think mapping this function across your result will make complete output: `extend = Sequence @@ Table[RotateRight[#, n], {n, 0,
      FirstPosition[Reverse@#, _?Positive][[1]] - 1}] &;`

Comment: I  can suggest a nice fix to the preliminary version.  At the beginning just add 1 to both arguments of IntegerPartitions. Then after the flatting of the Permutations result, double the set by decrementing either the first or the last element of each list. Finally swap the arguments of the Riffle. I am however not sure, that this nice solution is faster than the one suggested by @Mr.Wisard. To my sorry I was not able to add the code realizing the decrement of the first and last element in a nice way you are using Mathematica. I would very appreciate if you show how to do this.

Comment: My suggestion has appeared wrong. It produces unnecessary duplicates. I will post the correct solution (without claiming it is an efficient one) below.

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.Wizard. I will add it once checked.

Comment: deleted deleted

Answer (score 3):

Not efficient but:

```
func[lst_, n_] := 
 Module[{perm = Permutations[lst~Join~Table[0, n - Length[lst]]],
   r = {0 ...}~Join~Riffle[lst, 0 ..]~Join~{0 ...}},
  DeleteCases[Cases[perm, r], {_?(# != 0 &), ___, __?(# != 0 &)}]]
```

e.g.

```
Row[MatrixPlot[#, ImageSize -> 100] & /@ (func[Range[3], #] & /@ 
    Range[6, 9])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very quick-n-dirty entry. Seems fast as is, will revisit re: tuning when time permits.

```
do[l_, n_] :=
  Join @@ (NestList[RotateLeft, Flatten[Riffle[#, l]], 
       Length[#[[1]]]] & /@ Join @@ Permutations /@ 
          Map[ConstantArray[0, #] &, IntegerPartitions[n - Length@l, {Length@l}, 
               Range[1, n - Length@l + 1]], {2}]);
```

Usage:

```
do[{1,2,3},7]
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 
>     0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3},
>
> {1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0,
>      3}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0}}

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to thank everybody who took part in the discussion. I am still sure that `shuffleW`is probably the best choice to adapt for my problem. The other promising option were the indexing proposed by  @Carl Woll. However it certainly exceeds my current level.

Yet I would like to present an algorithm correcting the version of @march. The algorithm is certainly not efficient enough, but it gives the correct answer without intermediate producing  of reduntant sequences.

```
solution[in_List,n_]:=Module[{k=Length[in],s,ss},
s=Flatten[Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[n-k,{k+1}],1];
ss=Flatten[Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[n-k,{k}],1];
s=Join[Append[0]/@ss,s,Prepend[0]/@ss];
s=Table[0,{#}]&/@#&/@s; (* Taken from @march. Amusing construction. *) 
Table[Flatten[Riffle[s[[i]],in]],{i,Length[s]}]
]
```

`solution[{1,2,3},7]`

`{{0,0,1,0,2,0,3},{0,1,0,0,2,0,3},{0,1,0,2,0,0,3},{0,1,0,2,0,3,0},{1,0,0,2,0,3,0},{1,0,2,0,0,3,0},{1,0,2,0,3,0,0}}`

Besides the code

`solution[{},7]`

results in:

`{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}`,

which was very desired (I forgot to mention it in my question).

============= EDIT 26.02.2017

On the advice of Mr.Wisard I have tried to adapt `shuffleW` code to my problem. I report here on the result.

First of all a function generating allowed binary permutations was constructed:

```
rp[m_,n_] := Module[{p,q,nn=Binomial[n,m],mm=Binomial[n-1,m-1],i,j,k},
If[n<m,Return[{{}}]];
p=ConstantArray[0,{mm+nn,m+n}];
q=Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1,m],ConstantArray[0,n-m]]];
For[j=1,j≤mm,j++,k=1;For[i=1,i≤n,i++,If[q[[j,i]]==1,p[[j,k]]=1;k++];k++]];
For[j=1,j≤nn,j++,k=1;For[i=1,i≤n,i++,If[q[[j,i]]==1,k++;p[[j+mm,k]]=1];k++]];
p
]
```

Further the `shuffleW` code was reduced to:

```
shuffle0[s_, n_] := Module[{p, ord},
p = rp[Length[s],n-Length[s]]//Transpose;
ord = Accumulate[p] p + 1;
Outer[Part, {Join[{0}, s]}, ord, 1][[1]]//Transpose
]
```

The resulting code seems to be quite fast.

With original `shuffleW` code one can readily solve a more general problem. Given two sets s1,s2 (Length[s1]<=Length[s2]) find all the "shuffled" sequences, in which the elements of s1 are cyclically separated by at least one element of s2.

```
shuffleA[s1_,s2_] := Module[{p,tp,ord},
p = rp[Length[s1],Length[s2]]//Transpose;
tp = BitXor[p, 1];
ord = Accumulate[p] p + (Accumulate[tp] + Length[s1]) tp;
Outer[Part, {Join[s1,s2]}, ord, 1][[1]]//Transpose
]
```

Comment: By the way the algorithm provides a simple check for the overall number of the sequences: `N=2Binomial[n-k-1,k-1]+Binomial[n-k-1,k]=Binomial[n-k-1,k-1]+Binomial[n-k,k]`.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You post "I am looking for an efficient solution...", then post an answer, after several others answer with efficient solutions, a solution with rather mediocre performance for non-trivial cases. What exactly was the purpose here?

Comment: @ciao I think you misunderstand. drer did not self-accept this. (And I will be disappointed if he does.)  Instead he completed march's partial method in a different way from what I proposed.  I think this is an interesting contribution even if inefficient.

Comment: @ciao Mr.Wisard is absolutely right. My intention was solely to complete the march's solution, to make it producing correct result. You are also wrong  that  there were a lot of answers with efficient solutions. No of them (maybe except of yours, which I did not see at that time) gave the correct result without some refining (with unknown efficiency). Besides I wrote explicitely that I do not consider "my" solution as an efficient one. Actually I would prefer a form of a comment instead, but it allows too few characters. I will introduce minor changes to my answer to clarify this point.

Answer (score -1):

Step by step:

```
mylist = {1, 2, 3};
```

Separate by a single 0:

```
list2 = Riffle[mylist, 0]

(* 
   {1, 0, 2, 0, 3}
*)
```

Add a zero at the beginning, and separately add a zero at the end:

```
list3 = {Prepend[list2, 0], Append[list2, 0]}

(* 
   {{0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}}
*)
```

For each list [`Insert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Insert.html) a 0 in every non-zero [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html), plus the end, and eliminate duplicates.

```
addZero[lists : {__List}] :=
  Union @@ Table[
    Insert[a, 0, #] & /@ Position[Unitize @ Append[a, 1], 1],
    {a, lists}
  ]

addZero[list3]

(*
   {{0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3},
    {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0},
    {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0}}
*)
```

Repeat the application of `addZero` for every zero to be added, i.e. [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html).

Comment: Your answer seems to be neither general nor complete.

Comment: David, I don't like seeing your answer languishing in the negative so I completed your method and revised your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:  Many thanks for your efforts.  I really appreciate it.  (I've been swamped with other tasks and unable to devote the time to improving my "negative" answer.)